# XSLT transform a document with group element

Tags: xslt

I have a document like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="1" attribute3="1">Director</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="1" attribute3="5">James</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="1" attribute3="8">Male</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="1" attribute3="9">10-Dec-1965</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="2" attribute3="18">James@gmail.com</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="2" attribute3="1">Chief Account</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="2" attribute3="5">Anna</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="2" attribute3="8">Female</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="1" attribute3="9">5-Aug-1980</data>
    <data attribute1="12" attribute2="2" attribute3="18">Anna@gmail.com</data>
</document>
```

I want to transform it to this:

```
<Person>
    <Title>Director</Title>
    <FullName>James</FullName>
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
    <DateOfBirth>10-Dec-1965</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>James@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Title>Chief Account</Title>
    <FullName>Anna</FullName>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
    <DateOfBirth>5-Aug-1980</DateOfBirth>
    <EmailAddress>Anna@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
</Person>
```

I am using this xslt:

```
<xsl:for-each select="document/data[@attribute1=12]">
    <Person>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="boolean(./@attribute3 = '1')">
                <Title>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./."/>
                </Title>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="boolean(./@attribute3 = '5')">
                <FullName>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./."/>
                </FullName>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="boolean(./@attribute3 = '8')">
                <Gender>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./."/>
                </Gender>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="boolean(./@attribute3 = '9')">
                <DateOfBirth>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./."/>
                </DateOfBirth>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="boolean(./@attribute3 = '18')">
                <EmailAddress>
                    <xsl:value-of select="./."/>
                </EmailAddress>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </Person>
</xsl:for-each>
```

The problem is that I get the following output, where the `<Person>` tag is duplicated.

```
<Person>
    <Title>Director</Title>
</Person>    
<Person>    
    <FullName>James</FullName>
</Person>    
<Person>  
    <Gender>Male</Gender>
</Person>
<Person>    
    <DateOfBirth>10-Dec-1965</DateOfBirth>
</Person>    
<Person>    
    <EmailAddress>James@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Title>Chief Account</Title>
</Person>
<Person>
    <FullName>Anna</FullName>
</Person>
<Person>
    <Gender>Female</Gender>
</Person>
<Person>
    <DateOfBirth>5-Aug-1980</DateOfBirth>
</Person>
<Person>
    <EmailAddress>Anna@gmail.com</EmailAddress>
</Person>
```

Could anyone help me solving this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Please show that output. Is it correct that one of the persons has two DateOfBirths and the other has none, or am I misunderstanding your mapping?

Comment: Are you able to use XSLT 2.0, as you could potentially use the **xsl:for-each-group** function here.

Comment: @Jongware: there are two people and each person has the own DateOfBirth (James-1965 & Anna 1980). The first five elements belongs to James' info and the five follower belongs to Anna' info.

Comment: @Tim C: my system just support xslt 1.0

Comment: @user2713222: so it's not an error that for both DateOfBirths the value of `attribute2="1"`? Then I *did* misunderstand the mapping, have to think a bit further on a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you wish to create a new **Person** element for each **data** element with an **attribute3** value of 1. Rather than iterate over all **data** elements as you are currently doing, just select the elements with the relevant attribute

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="data[@attribute3='1']"/>
```

Then, you would have a template to output the **Person** element only for these **data** elements.

```
<xsl:template match="data[@attribute3='1']">
   <Person>
      <Title><xsl:value-of select="." /></Title>
      <!-- Select other elements here -->
   </Person>
</xsl:template>
```

Now, to get the other elements, another way to achieve this is to make use of a key. Effectively, you will group the **data** elements by the first most preceding **data** element with an **attribute3** value of "1".

```
<xsl:key name="data" 
         match="data[@attribute3 != '1']" 
         use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::data[@attribute3 = '1'][1])" />
```

Then, to select the other elements, you can use this key, using the unique ID of the current **data** element as the lookup.

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="key('data', generate-id())" />
```

This would only select the **data** elements that make up that particular person element. You would then have template to match the other **data** elements for each possible attribute value:

Try this XSLT :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
   <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

   <xsl:key name="data" match="data[@attribute3 != '1']" use="generate-id(preceding-sibling::data[@attribute3 = '1'][1])" />

   <xsl:template match="document">
         <xsl:apply-templates select="data[@attribute3='1']"/>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="data[@attribute3='1']">
      <Person>
         <Title><xsl:value-of select="." /></Title>
         <xsl:apply-templates select="key('data', generate-id())" />
      </Person>
   </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="data[@attribute3='5']">
      <FullName><xsl:value-of select="." /></FullName>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data[@attribute3='8']">
      <Gender><xsl:value-of select="." /></Gender>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data[@attribute3='9']">
      <DateOfBirth><xsl:value-of select="." /></DateOfBirth>
   </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="data[@attribute3='18']">
      <EmailAddress><xsl:value-of select="." /></EmailAddress>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank Tim for your specified guides. That is the answer I expected

Comment: Bear in mind, this answer is based on the position of the elements, and not the value of **attribute2** in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion based on the position of elements:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:param name="size" select="5"/>

<xsl:template match="document">
  <Persons>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="data[position() mod $size = 1]" mode="group"/>
  </Persons>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data" mode="group">
  <Person>
    <xsl:apply-templates select=". | following-sibling::data[position() &lt; $size]"/>
  </Person>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data[@attribute3 = '1']">
  <Title>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Title>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data[@attribute3 = '5']">
  <FullName>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </FullName>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data[@attribute3 = '8']">
  <Gender>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </Gender>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data[@attribute3 = '9']">
  <DateOfBirth>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </DateOfBirth>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="data[@attribute3 = '18']">
  <EmailAddress>
    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
  </EmailAddress>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thanks Martin. It works perfectly. But in case of the size is not specified, how to define the size base on the attribute2. Because attribute2 is changed for each group info of a person.

Comment: I don't understand why you say that `attribute2` is changed for each group as your sample input has two `data` elements with dates inside that have the same `attribute2` (i.e. `"1"`). So at least with your sample data that attribute does not seem to help to relate elements to persons. If the `data` elements can be grouped by the `attribute2` value then standard Muenchian grouping could be applied. Please correct your sample data. Or explain in more detail how the order of elements and `attribute2` relates `data` elements to persons.